# How is PutIf different from PutIfExists and PutIfNotExists

Tags: scalardb

I am using `ScalarDB` which adds ACID support in `Cassandra`. Referring to the documentation, how is `PutIf` different from `PutIfExists` and `PutIfNotExists`?

I suppose
`PutIfExists` is like an update
`PutIfNotExists` is like a new addition

What is PutIf? When to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PutIf` can add conditions to update a record. You can use `PutIfExists` when you want to just **update** without any other condition. On the other hand, You have to use `PutIfNotExists` when you want to **insert** a new record without unexpected overwriting.

For example, a table has a record as below.
We want to update the `pass` of a record if the score is greater than or equal to 60.
(We assume that records have been inserted beforehand, and we have calculated the threshold (mean, median, etc.), then we decide the ID can pass the threshold or not.)

```
|pID|cID|score| pass|
|  0|  0|   80|false|
|  1|  0|   45|false|
```

The following `put` will update the first record to set `true` in `pass`.

```java
PartitionKey pk = new Key(new IntValue("pID", 0));
ClusteringKey ck = new Key(new IntValue("cID", 0));

PutIf condition = new PutIf(new ConditionalExpression("score", new IntValue(60), Operator.GTE));

Put put = new Put(pk, ck).withValue(new BooleanValue("pass", true)).withCondition(condition);

storage.put(put);
```

If we try to update the second record with the same condition, it won't be updated because the score is less than 60.

Comment: So `PutIfNotExists` and `PutIfExists` work on existence of record while `putIf` will work only if record exists? In your example the `put` will not work for say `pID`=1 because it doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: > PutIfNotExists and PutIfExists work on existence of record while putIf will work only if record exists?

Right.